# Toggle Hidden Files without Relaunching Finder

Tags: finder, applescript

I'm pretty new here, and I looked for an answer to this question, and found some answers but none seemed to work for me.

I want to be able to run an applescript that toggles hidden files and immediately updates all the open finder windows.

Using the scripts in these threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135878/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-toggle-hide-show-hidden-files-on-a-mac-os-x-yosemite

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788558/automator-command-to-refresh-all-finder-all-finder-windows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469894/how-to-make-a-script-to-show-hide-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x

I've come up with something that looks like this:

```
try
    set state to (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles") as boolean
on error
    set state to false
end try

do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & (not state)

tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view
        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

However, as of my version of OS X (10.11.5), this doesn't actually toggle the hidden files.  I need to relaunch finder in order to see the changes.  I know how to do this in the script with: `do shell script "killall Finder"`, but I don't know how to get all my current windows back and repositioned to where they were.

**TL;DR**: Is there a nice way to force the Finder windows to refresh without having to relaunch Finder?  Or if there isn't, how can I keep my windows after a restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick of switching views worked well in Yosemite but no longer in El Capitan.

I've had to go back to the simple, yet annoying

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState & "; killall Finder"
```

Rather than the much nicer version which worked before

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState    

tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

*Honestly, I'd love this answer to be wrong*

BTW, Windows ought to reopen exactly where they were - but not if you have them spread over more than one Space; that's not possible.

Comment: so if i understand correctly, pre-OS 10.11 with Tetsujin's first script, you COULD show/hide the hidden files withOUT the Finder relaunching, but you cannot post-OS 10.10? that seems ridiculous (IMO). how come apps like Panic's Transmit FTP program can show/hide without relaunching it & the Finder can't? would LOVE to find an app to simply toggle this in ONE Finder window, not all.